# MySQL - Trigger with UPDATE statement inside of IF/THEN

Tags: mysql, triggers

Am I allowed to put this UPDATE statement within this IF/THEN clause? The trigger below fails to update signups in tbl_user_stats.  I am sure that date_now is greater than 0.

I have seen examples where the SET clause is nested within the IF/THEN clause, but I don't know if/how I should do it in this case.

```
 drop trigger if exists upd_signedup$$


CREATE TRIGGER upd_signedup
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE date_now date;
    SET date_now = (SELECT count(*) from tbl_user_stats WHERE DATE(todays_date) =         CURDATE());
    IF date_now > 0 THEN
    UPDATE tbl_user_stats SET signups = signups + 1 WHERE DATE(todays_date) = CURDATE();
    END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: Try declaring `date_now` as an INT.

Comment: Thanks, that was a stupid mistake.